# Where and when do we need to use api names in triggers?

Tags: apex, trigger

Where and when do we need to use `API Names` in  `Apex Triggers`?

Answer (score 4):

Apex code references data fields and objects via API names rather than labels. This means the code will not break if the label is changed or translated. So in triggers you always use the API names.

A good place to start learning about triggers is Trailhead [Apex Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/apex_triggers).

But if you are new to IT and Salesforce I suggest you spend time on the [Salesforce Platform Basics](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/starting_force_com) and other introductory [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead) material too.